# How to handle errors in service layer using the routes , controller , service , repo pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

As in nestjs i was to separate the concernes, handling errors in nestjs is easy for me , now i want to do the same in express , i used to put all the logic in the controller passing req,res,next to this controller , now how can i add service layer to write my business logic and a repo later to access the database and in the same time to handle the errors in the service layer.

in the old way i used to pass the error to return next , now in the service i do not have this 'next' so please someone help me to do that iam stuck in this for a few days

Comment: You can use `throw` to return the error from service and your controller can `catch` that. Do the things you need to do after catching it and then use `next` for sending it back to the caller.